# Handsontable is having issues - single row with readonly cells

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using handsontable in my project. It was working perfectly till last week.

Last two days it is not working (displaying single row with readonly cells).

I don't know the issue and I ensure that I didn't change anything in the code.

```
hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('Scid'), {   
      rowHeaders: true,
      minCols: 23,
      maxCols: 23,
      columnSorting: true,
      colHeaders :['IssuerCode','ProductCode','ComponentCode','VariantCode','Platform','TrackingCode','MedicalPlanCode','PharmacyPlanCode','AvValue','MetallicLevel','Riders','Network','ScidStatus','ContributionAmountMin'
                ,'ContributionAmountMax','HIOSDescriptor','HIOSReason','LinkedHIOS','CaseEffectiveDate','GeoRating','DiscontinueDate','NewExisting','Note'],                       
      minSpareRows: 1
    });
```

Anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some special characters between ContributionAmountMin and ContributionAmountMax. ['IssuerCode','ProductCode','ComponentCode','VariantCode','Platform','TrackingCode','MedicalPlanCode','PharmacyPlanCode','AvValue','MetallicLevel','Riders','Network','ScidStatus','ContributionAmountMin'
                ,'ContributionAmountMax','HIOSDescriptor','HIOSReason','LinkedHIOS','CaseEffectiveDate','GeoRating','DiscontinueDate','NewExisting','Note']

Removing the extra spaces and carriage returns should resolve the issue.

Comment: I have verified it. There are no issues in the column names, Even I have tried by removing it.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?